# SVG animation - make eyes follow cursor

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, svg

I have this SVG of a face. I would like to have the group of eyes follow my cursors movement so I don't have to make separate divs for the eyes

```
<g id="eyes">
    <g id="right-eye">
        <circle id="right-pupil" class="st0" cx="135" cy="137.5" r="6"/>
    </g>
    <g id="left-eye">
        <circle id="left-pupil" class="st0" cx="70.4" cy="137.5" r="6"/>
    </g>
</g>
```

I would like it to act like the eyes to act like in this pen: http://codepen.io/wojtek1150/pen/jqVbpK

Here is what i have so far, that doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/kLbmL01q/2/

Is it possible to animate the eyes within the SVG?

Comment: you do not include jquery... looking at the dev console help in most cases;)

Comment: You can't make the eyes animated using `top` and `left` (I tried.) You need to use the `cx` and `cy` attributes of the SVG circle to move it around.

Comment: Also, your mousemove function always returns coordinates of 0 and 0, no matter where the mouse is moved.

Comment: Jquery has now been included, but this didn't help. 

I am new to svg animation what should 'cx' and 'cy' coordinates be?

Comment: I'm figuring that out, hold on...

Comment: Why do you want to do it with SVG?

Comment: I would prefer to do it with SVG, since I then can control size and fill color all in one svg instead of svg and divs

Comment: Check this, https://codepen.io/GabEsu/pen/VdKjPE